# How can I call a c++ function from another file in Cython?

Tags: c++, cython

I have written a function to trim the spaces from a string in c++ and I wish to call it from a another file. The whole thing is called from a Python script using a Cython wrapper

If I do not call *trim* in *main.cpp* the program runs; if I do, I get the run-time error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeff/projects/c/bfg/trim_test/trim_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import trim_binder
ImportError: ./libmain.so: undefined symbol: _Z4trimRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Apologies for the amount of code; I've trimmed it back as much as I can. It can be cloned with

```
git clone https://psionman@bitbucket.org/psionman/test_trim.git
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_TRIM_H
#define TEST_TRIM_H

#include <iostream>

std::string testTrim(std::string);

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "trim.h"

std::string testTrim(std::string line) {
  std::string trimmed {};
  trimmed = line;
  trimmed = trim(line);
  return trimmed;
}
```

**trim.h**

```
#ifndef TRIM_STRINGS_H
#define TRIM_STRINGS_H

std::string& trim(std::string& s);

#endif
```

**trim.cpp**
#include 
#include "trim.h"

```
    // trim from left
    inline std::string& ltrim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t\n\r\f\v")
    {
        s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
        return s;
    }

    // trim from right
    inline std::string& rtrim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t\n\r\f\v")
    {
        s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
        return s;
    }

    // trim from left & right
    inline std::string& trim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t\n\r\f\v")
    {
        return ltrim(rtrim(s, t), t);
    }
```

**trim_test.py**

```
import trim_binder

line = '  AAA BB  CC E   '
trimmed = trim_binder.get_trimmed_text(line)
print(f'In trim_test: {trimmed.replace(" ", ".")}')
```

**trim_wrapper.pyx**

```
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from 'main.h':
    string testTrim(char* input_text)

def get_trimmed_text(path):
    input_text = str.encode(str(path))
    py_bytes_object = input_text
    cdef string s = py_bytes_object

    raw_trimmed = testTrim(py_bytes_object)
    trimmed = raw_trimmed.decode()
    return trimmed
```

The compilation uses the *invoke* package

**tasks.py**
import invoke

```
WRAPPER_NAME = 'trim_wrapper.cpp'
BINDER = 'trim_binder'  # .pyx file name
C_FILE = 'main'
compile_files = ['main', 'trim']


@invoke.task()
def build_c_function(c):
    """Build the shared library for the sample C++ code"""

    files = [file + '.cpp' for file in compile_files]
    files_str = ' '.join(files)
    invoke.run(
        f'g++ -O3 -Wall -Werror -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC {files_str} '
        '-I . '
        f'-o lib{C_FILE}.so '
    )
    print('c function build complete')


def compile_python_module(cpp_name, extension_name):
    invoke.run(
        'g++ -O3 -Wall -Werror -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC '
        '`python3 -m pybind11 --includes` '
        '-I . '
        '{0} '
        '-o {1}`python3-config --extension-suffix` '
        f'-L. -l{C_FILE} -Wl,-rpath,.'.format(cpp_name, extension_name)
    )


@invoke.task(build_c_function)
def build_cython(c):
    """Build the cython extension module"""
    invoke.run(f'cython --cplus -3 {BINDER}.pyx -o {WRAPPER_NAME}')
    compile_python_module(WRAPPER_NAME, BINDER)
    print('cython build complete')
```

Here is the symbol list for **libmain.so**

```
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __gxx_personality_v0@CXXABI_1.3
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U _Unwind_Resume@GCC_3.0
0000000000001140 T _Z8testTrimNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
                 U _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE10_M_disposeEv@GLIBCXX_3.4.21
                 U _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_assignERKS4_@GLIBCXX_3.4.21
                 U _ZSt21ios_base_library_initv@GLIBCXX_3.4.32
```

And [this is a link](https://pastebin.com/iC3hXzer) to the symbol list for **trim_binder.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
** which is rather long

Comment: What symbols are exported by the built extension module? Specifically those that contain `trim`

Comment: @Botje If I've understood correctly main.cpp just exposes testTrim

Comment: The name of the symbol is not just `trim`. Edit your question with the exact name of the exported symbol so we can rule out cxx11 ABI problems

Comment: @Botje I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Where do I find these symbols? I can see that the error message contains the word symbol, but I thought that symbol was compiler generated

Comment: You can interrogate a library for its needed and exported symbols using `nm`. The names must match exactly for it to be found.

Comment: @Botje Symbol lists added to question

Answer (score 0):

In `main.cpp` and `trim.cpp`, you aren't include the standard library header file `<string>` (which is where the definition of string lives). You include `<iostream>`. This may well include *some* of `<string>` but possibly not all, and some bits may only be forward declared.

I'd think the line `#include <string>` should go in `trim.h`

I'm not sure if that's the complete issue but it's certainly a mistake.